# Custom error pages for StaticFile handler

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I am trying to get custom error pages to work for any URL which isn't otherwise handled or isn't a valid file on disk.

I have the following setup now:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Error404" />
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <remove statusCode="500" />
    <error responseMode="ExecuteURL" statusCode="404" path="/Error/Error404" />
    <error responseMode="ExecuteURL" statusCode="500" path="/Error" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

This redirects correctly the following URLs:

- `/test`
- `/test/foo/bar`

However, anything that contains a period, gives the following message:

- **Module**       IIS Web Core
- **Notification**     MapRequestHandler
- **Handler**      StaticFile
- **Error Code**       `0x80070002`
- **Requested URL**        `https://localhost/test.txt`
- **Physical Path**    `C:\foo\test.txt`
- **Logon Method**     Anonymous
- **Logon User**       Anonymous

I need these URLs to also redirect to my custom error pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" .. />
```

However, be careful. I find I sometimes get loop conditions or that the IIS error page will execute ahead of my custom error module. The interfacing between IIS and ASP.NET app does not always play nice. I still can't seem to find a way to catch static file 404s in ASP.NET but fall through to the static file handler otherwise.